# I need to copy data from a file, "MusicLibrary.txt" to a strucutre. But when I'm using my code, it doesn't return anything

Tags: c

Here's my code for copying the file.

```
song_t *ReadFile(song_t *head){
FILE *input;
input = fopen("MusicLibrary.txt", "r");
song_t *temp = head;
string title;
string artist;
string album;
string genre;
string store;
string buffer;

while(fgets(buffer, MAXSIZE, input) != NULL){
    temp = (song_t *)malloc(sizeof(song_t));
    fgets(temp->title, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->artist, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->album, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->genre, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(store, MAXSIZE, input);
    temp->rating = atof(store);
    temp->next == NULL;
    temp = temp->next;
}

fclose(input);
return head;
}
```

and here is the code for my structre:

```
typedef struct song{
string title;
string artist;
string album;
string genre;
float rating;
struct song *next;
}song_t;
```

also, 
    typedef char string[30];

i can't seem to copy the data from files to the structure in main. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: temp = temp->next   --> you are throwing all of your new temp away again...

Comment: btw. ReadFile is a defined API on Windows, so I'm hoping you're doing this on a non-win-box or not including Windows.h =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAXSIZE, input) != NULL){
    temp = (song_t *)malloc(sizeof(song_t));
    fgets(temp->title, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->artist, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->album, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(temp->genre, MAXSIZE, input);
    fgets(store, MAXSIZE, input);
    temp->rating = atof(store);
    temp->next == NULL;
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

There are a few problems with the above code that may *not* be problems depending on you input file format, but here goes:

---

First, you control the `while` loop with a `fgets` that throws a line away. Are you certain that's what you wanted.

---

Secondly, you should always check the return value from `malloc` in case it fails.

---

Thirdly, you're assuming that each field is on its own line. You should confirm that.

---

Fourth, you're not really inserting correctly into a linked list. If your intent is to insert new items at the start of the list, change:

```
temp->next == NULL;
temp = temp->next;
```

into:

```
temp->next == head;
head = temp;
```

and ensure you call it as:

```
actualHead = ReadFile (actualHead);
```

to update the `head` pointer correctly.

---

Comment: +1. Only comment is on the third point, and as you said his file format makes this a crapshoot. if the input lines are longer than MASIZE-1 before the newline multiple entry reads from a single are possible.

Comment: I got it! Thanks by the way. I did everything you said, and it went fine. Thank you!